# too large table

Tags: tables

this is my data for a table. How to make it fit in an a4 pager

```
Pixels & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50 \\ 
        \hline 
        1 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 0 & 9 & 0 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 2 & 10 & 4 & 10 & 2 & 9 & 3 & 2 & 9 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 5 & 1 \\ 
        \hline 
        2 & 10 & 1 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 0 & 6 & 4 & 7 & 1 & 9 & 2 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 8 & 2 & 9 & 5 & 9 & 7 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 1 & 3 & 10 & 2 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 5 & 3 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 6 \\ 
        \hline 
        3 & 7 & 6 & 6 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 2 & 10 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 9 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 3 & 9 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 5 & 9 & 10 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 10 & 7 & 7 & 3 & 9 & 3 & 9 & 2 & 3 & 9 & 8 \\ 
        \hline 
        4 & 5 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 5 & 6 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 1 & 9 & 3 & 8 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 9 & 7 & 0 & 9 & 1 & 4 & 9 & 9 & 8 & 9 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 7 & 9 \\ 
        \hline 
        5 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 5 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 9 & 4 & 3 & 8 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 8 & 7 & 2 & 4 & 9 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 1 & 3 & 9 & 1 & 4 & 8 & 8 \\ 
        \hline 
        6 & 2 & 8 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 7 & 4 & 10 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 7 & 2 & 8 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 5 & 9 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 10 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\ 
        \hline 
        7 & 10 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 9 & 10 & 8 & 7 & 0 & 9 & 0 & 9 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 7 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 9 & 7 & 6 & 8 & 1 & 4 & 9 & 9 & 7 & 8 & 4 & 3 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 9 & 2 & 9 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 5 & 8 & 1 & 5 & 7 \\ 
        \hline 
        8 & 3 & 7 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 1 & 7 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 10 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 10 & 2 & 8 & 3 & 9 & 10 & 1 & 8 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 9 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 2 & 9 & 4 & 1 \\ 
        \hline 
        9 & 10 & 6 & 10 & 4 & 9 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 9 & 7 & 5 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 4 & 9 & 4 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 1 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 2 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 9 & 3 & 5 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 5 & 2 & 7 \\ 
        \hline 
        10 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 7 & 8 & 2 & 0 & 9 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 7 & 4 & 8 & 0 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 7 & 0 & 3 & 7 & 7 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 1 & 8 & 5 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 4 \\ 
        \hline 
        11 & 6 & 5 & 1 & 10 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 8 & 0 & 9 & 3 & 4 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 9 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 9 & 8 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 6 & 10 \\ 
        \hline 
        12 & 8 & 5 & 10 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 1 & 10 & 5 & 0 & 10 & 1 & 8 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 9 & 7 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 5 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 10 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 8 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 4 & 7 & 3 & 6 & 4 \\ 
        \hline 
        13 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 12 & 13 & 7 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 4 & 9 & 3 & 6 & 6 & 3 & 9 & 7 & 8 & 5 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 10 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 6 & 10 & 5 & 10 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 9 & 1 & 6 & 7 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 6 \\ 
        \hline 
        14 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 10 & 4 & 10 & 0 & 9 & 202 & 798 & 206 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 7 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 5 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 9 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 7 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 7 \\ 
        \hline 
        15 & 1 & 8 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 1 & 6 & 14 & 803 & 3239 & 804 & 18 & 5 & 9 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 7 & 7 & 10 & 8 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 12 & 6 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 5 & 6 & 5 & 3 \\ 
        \hline 
        16 & 6 & 3 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 8 & 3 & 5 & 204 & 798 & 206 & 6 & 4 & 9 & 9 & 5 & 8 & 8 & 0 & 10 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 9 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 92 & 353 & 94 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\ 
        \hline 
        17 & 7 & 1 & 10 & 3 & 2 & 10 & 9 & 4 & 7 & 13 & 8 & 3 & 10 & 5 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 0 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 2 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 11 & 356 & 1426 & 355 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 8 & 3 & 9 \\ 
        \hline 
        18 & 3 & 6 & 8 & 9 & 6 & 1 & 9 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 7 & 0 & 10 & 7 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 8 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 7 & 3 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 9 & 8 & 8 & 89 & 351 & 96 & 6 & 8 & 4 & 7 & 4 & 4 & 0 & 9 & 3 \\ 
        \hline 
        19 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 4 & 8 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 1 & 6 & 0 & 10 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 6 & 6 & 2 & 9 & 0 & 7 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 12 & 8 & 2 & 9 & 7 & 3 & 2 & 8 & 7 & 7 & 8 \\ 
        \hline 
        20 & 6 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 9 & 6 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 6 & 5 & 8 & 10 & 2 & 1 & 7 & 9 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 7 & 9 & 10 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 10 & 7 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 9 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 5 & 8 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 9 & 3 & 5 \\ 
        \hline 
        21 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 8 & 7 & 1 & 8 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 10 & 8 & 2 & 5 & 10 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 7 & 5 & 6 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 10 & 4 & 6 & 1 & 10 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 3 & 6 & 1 & 6 & 10 & 9 & 2 \\ 
        \hline 1
        22 & 4 & 7 & 7 & 2 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 9 & 1 & 8 & 6 & 9 & 9 & 2 & 8 & 5 & 4 & 4 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 10 & 5 & 10 & 3 & 7 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 0 & 9 & 5 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 1 & 9 & 10 & 4 & 9 & 1 & 8 & 5 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 7 & 4 \\ 
        \hline 
        23 & 4 & 5 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 9 & 3 & 43 & 165 & 40 & 11 & 10 & 7 & 3 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 7 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 8 & 10 & 1 & 8 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 9 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 1 \\ 
        \hline 
        24 & 4 & 9 & 7 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 2 & 10 & 2 & 3 & 8 & 4 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 8 & 40 & 2665 & 10786 & 2667 & 42 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 1 & 9 & 7 & 10 & 3 & 1 & 10 & 6 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 9 & 10 & 2 & 3 & 10 & 9 & 6 & 5 & 6 & 1 \\ 
        \hline 
        25 & 5 & 7 & 4 & 8 & 1 & 7 & 7 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 6 & 3 & 9 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 165 & 10785 & 43705 & 10780 & 170 & 10 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 9 & 8 & 10 & 4 & 9 & 10 & 10 & 3 & 3 & 10 & 0 & 9 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 10 & 3 & 3 & 6 \\ 
        \hline 
        26 & 11 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 45 & 2663 & 10783 & 2658 & 47 & 10 & 2 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 5 & 2 & 5 & 10 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 6 & 9 & 8 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 5 & 0 \\ 
        \hline 
        27 & 4 & 6 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 9 & 3 & 1 & 9 & 4 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 10 & 2 & 2 & 8 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 4 & 44 & 164 & 42 & 3 & 3 & 9 & 3 & 9 & 6 & 4 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 10 & 6 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 9 & 1 \\ 
        \hline 
        28 & 1 & 9 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 7 & 6 & 10 & 9 & 9 & 3 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 6 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 10 & 2 & 6 & 9 & 1 & 5 & 8 & 5 & 9 & 5 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 10 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 0 & 2 \\ 
        \hline 
        29 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 9 & 1 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 2 & 1 & 9 & 9 & 2 & 7 & 10 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 9 & 6 & 0 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 0 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 0 & 6 & 6 & 0 & 9 & 9 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 6 & 6 \\ 
        \hline 
        30 & 2 & 1 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 9 & 2 & 0 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 10 & 5 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 10 & 2 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 5 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 4 & 6 & 1 & 3 & 8 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 8 & 5 \\ 
        \hline 
        31 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 8 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 10 & 4 & 0 & 7 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 9 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 1 & 9 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 7 & 5 & 0 & 8 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 5 & 9 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 6 & 0 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\ 
        \hline 
        32 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 9 & 3 & 5 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 9 & 8 & 5 & 3 & 6 & 8 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 2 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 8 & 5 & 5 & 9 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 5 & 10 & 2 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 1 & 3 & 4 \\ 
        \hline 
        33 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 9 & 9 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 9 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 10 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 9 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 3 \\ 
        \hline 
        34 & 5 & 7 & 0 & 9 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 5 & 10 & 9 & 10 & 8 & 10 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 8 & 9 & 4 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 27 & 94 & 24 & 2 & 2 & 5 & 10 \\ 
        \hline 
        35 & 7 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 9 & 7 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 3 & 9 & 6 & 9 & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 8 & 2 & 9 & 7 & 1 & 9 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 5 & 7 & 3 & 9 & 11 & 95 & 355 & 96 & 7 & 7 & 8 & 8 \\ 
        \hline 
        36 & 1 & 10 & 2 & 8 & 8 & 3 & 0 & 7 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 0 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 8 & 6 & 5 & 5 & 0 & 2 & 8 & 10 & 10 & 23 & 94 & 25 & 8 & 7 & 0 & 8 \\ 
        \hline 
        37 & 7 & 9 & 7 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 8 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 9 & 0 & 7 & 2 & 5 & 9 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 7 & 10 & 7 & 4 & 6 & 2 & 9 & 6 & 6 & 9 & 11 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 10 & 2 \\ 
        \hline 
        38 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 5 & 7 & 6 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 8 & 7 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 9 & 1 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 6 & 4 & & 2 & 4 & 9 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 3 & 0 \\ 
        \hline 
        39 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 8 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 10 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 9 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 0 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 6 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 6 & 2 \\ 
        \hline 
        40 & 1 & 8 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 7 & 10 & 7 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 9 & 3 & 7 & 9 & 9 & 7 & 6 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 0 & 14 & 38 & 12 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 4 \\ 
        \hline 
        41 & 6 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 4 & 8 & 10 & 7 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 9 & 2 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 7 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 7 & 9 & 6 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 15 & 505 & 2041 & 510 & 9 & 0 & 1 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 9 & 8 & 10 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
        \hline 
        42 & 1 & 7 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 4 & 9 & 1 & 8 & 2 & 9 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 2 & 7 & 8 & 2 & 0 & 9 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 6 & 7 & 37 & 2040 & 8236 & 2031 & 35 & 7 & 7 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 7 & 2 & 5 & 2 & 0 & 8 \\ 
        \hline 
        43 & 1 & 7 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 10 & 4 & 8 & 7 & 7 & 2 & 7 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 7 & 10 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 16 & 508 & 2040 & 504 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 9 & 2 & 7 & 7 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 7 \\ 
        \hline 
        44 & 8 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 7 & 10 & 10 & 4 & 1 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 10 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 10 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 40 & 10 & 2 & 8 & 3 & 3 & 7 & 4 & 9 & 9 & 2 & 7 & 3 & 1 \\ 
        \hline 
        45 & 5 & 10 & 8 & 8 & 4 & 10 & 8 & 5 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 8 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 9 & 2 & 9 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 6 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 4 & 10 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 3 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 8 & 1 & 1 \\ 
        \hline 
        46 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 0 & 9 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 2 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 10 & 6 & 8 & 7 & 8 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 8 & 10 & 2 & 1 & 9 & 9 & 0 & 6 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 0 \\ 
        \hline 
        47 & 7 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 8 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 0 & 10 & 1 & 6 & 8 & 6 & 8 & 0 & 6 & 2 & 10 & 2 & 10 & 8 & 5 & 8 & 6 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 9 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 9 & 8 & 10 & 3 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 5 \\ 
        \hline 
        48 & 1 & 8 & 2 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 2 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 6 & 2 & 8 & 4 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 8 & 4 & 0 & 8 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 7 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 7 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 9 & 9 & 3 & 9 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 1 \\ 
        \hline 
        49 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 1 & 1 & 5 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 8 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 8 & 10 & 8 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 6 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 9 & 3 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 0 & 9 & 8 \\ 
        \hline 
        50 & 6 & 2 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 7 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 6 & 2 & 7 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 8 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 7 & 0 & 5 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 7 & 7 & 0 & 1 & 6 \\ 
        \hline
```

Comment: Use something like `\small` or `\scriptsize` before the `\begin{tabular}`.

Comment: I didn't notice at first how many columns you have. Fitting that in one page and still being readable seems...unlikely.

Comment: It seems unlikely that this is ever going to be a readable table. Maybe you should think about a way to present the data differently. Via a diagram for example. Or you could think about a way to split the table into several tables that are easier to digest for your reader and handle for TeX.

Comment: @TeXnician, you're absolutely right. This is what I get for disappearing from the site for 5 or so years.

Comment: @TH. Well, we've got some of those "FAQ-reference-question" posts now, which are pretty helpful concerning dups.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sideways table. Note that one of your rows has one too many elements. I simply deleted the last element. I also used `booktabs` to make it look a little better.

[image]

It's really not readable.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Some large table involving pixels.}
\tiny
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{51}{r}@{}}
\toprule
Pixels & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50 \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 0 & 9 & 0 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 2 & 10 & 4 & 10 & 2 & 9 & 3 & 2 & 9 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 5 & 1 \\
2 & 10 & 1 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 0 & 6 & 4 & 7 & 1 & 9 & 2 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 8 & 2 & 9 & 5 & 9 & 7 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 1 & 3 & 10 & 2 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 5 & 3 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 6 \\
3 & 7 & 6 & 6 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 2 & 10 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 9 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 3 & 9 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 5 & 9 & 10 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 10 & 7 & 7 & 3 & 9 & 3 & 9 & 2 & 3 & 9 & 8 \\
4 & 5 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 5 & 6 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 1 & 9 & 3 & 8 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 9 & 7 & 0 & 9 & 1 & 4 & 9 & 9 & 8 & 9 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 7 & 9 \\
5 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 5 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 9 & 4 & 3 & 8 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 8 & 7 & 2 & 4 & 9 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 1 & 3 & 9 & 1 & 4 & 8 & 8 \\
6 & 2 & 8 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 7 & 4 & 10 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 7 & 2 & 8 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 5 & 9 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 10 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
7 & 10 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 9 & 10 & 8 & 7 & 0 & 9 & 0 & 9 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 7 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 9 & 7 & 6 & 8 & 1 & 4 & 9 & 9 & 7 & 8 & 4 & 3 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 9 & 2 & 9 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 5 & 8 & 1 & 5 & 7 \\
8 & 3 & 7 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 1 & 7 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 10 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 10 & 2 & 8 & 3 & 9 & 10 & 1 & 8 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 9 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 2 & 9 & 4 & 1 \\
9 & 10 & 6 & 10 & 4 & 9 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 9 & 7 & 5 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 4 & 9 & 4 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 1 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 2 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 9 & 3 & 5 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 5 & 2 & 7 \\
10 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 7 & 8 & 2 & 0 & 9 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 7 & 4 & 8 & 0 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 7 & 0 & 3 & 7 & 7 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 1 & 8 & 5 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 4 \\
11 & 6 & 5 & 1 & 10 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 8 & 0 & 9 & 3 & 4 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 9 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 9 & 8 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 6 & 10 \\
12 & 8 & 5 & 10 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 1 & 10 & 5 & 0 & 10 & 1 & 8 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 9 & 7 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 5 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 10 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 8 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 4 & 7 & 3 & 6 & 4 \\
13 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 12 & 13 & 7 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 4 & 9 & 3 & 6 & 6 & 3 & 9 & 7 & 8 & 5 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 10 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 6 & 10 & 5 & 10 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 9 & 1 & 6 & 7 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 6 \\
14 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 10 & 4 & 10 & 0 & 9 & 202 & 798 & 206 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 7 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 5 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 9 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 7 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 7 \\
15 & 1 & 8 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 1 & 6 & 14 & 803 & 3239 & 804 & 18 & 5 & 9 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 7 & 7 & 10 & 8 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 12 & 6 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 5 & 6 & 5 & 3 \\
16 & 6 & 3 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 8 & 3 & 5 & 204 & 798 & 206 & 6 & 4 & 9 & 9 & 5 & 8 & 8 & 0 & 10 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 9 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 92 & 353 & 94 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
17 & 7 & 1 & 10 & 3 & 2 & 10 & 9 & 4 & 7 & 13 & 8 & 3 & 10 & 5 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 0 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 2 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 11 & 356 & 1426 & 355 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 8 & 3 & 9 \\
18 & 3 & 6 & 8 & 9 & 6 & 1 & 9 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 7 & 0 & 10 & 7 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 8 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 7 & 3 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 9 & 8 & 8 & 89 & 351 & 96 & 6 & 8 & 4 & 7 & 4 & 4 & 0 & 9 & 3 \\
19 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 4 & 8 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 1 & 6 & 0 & 10 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 6 & 6 & 2 & 9 & 0 & 7 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 12 & 8 & 2 & 9 & 7 & 3 & 2 & 8 & 7 & 7 & 8 \\
20 & 6 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 9 & 6 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 6 & 5 & 8 & 10 & 2 & 1 & 7 & 9 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 7 & 9 & 10 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 10 & 7 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 9 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 5 & 8 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 9 & 3 & 5 \\
21 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 8 & 7 & 1 & 8 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 10 & 8 & 2 & 5 & 10 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 7 & 5 & 6 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 10 & 4 & 6 & 1 & 10 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 3 & 6 & 1 & 6 & 10 & 9 & 2 \\
22 & 4 & 7 & 7 & 2 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 9 & 1 & 8 & 6 & 9 & 9 & 2 & 8 & 5 & 4 & 4 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 10 & 5 & 10 & 3 & 7 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 0 & 9 & 5 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 1 & 9 & 10 & 4 & 9 & 1 & 8 & 5 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 7 & 4 \\
23 & 4 & 5 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 9 & 3 & 43 & 165 & 40 & 11 & 10 & 7 & 3 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 7 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 8 & 10 & 1 & 8 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 9 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 1 \\
24 & 4 & 9 & 7 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 2 & 10 & 2 & 3 & 8 & 4 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 8 & 40 & 2665 & 10786 & 2667 & 42 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 1 & 9 & 7 & 10 & 3 & 1 & 10 & 6 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 9 & 10 & 2 & 3 & 10 & 9 & 6 & 5 & 6 & 1 \\
25 & 5 & 7 & 4 & 8 & 1 & 7 & 7 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 6 & 3 & 9 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 165 & 10785 & 43705 & 10780 & 170 & 10 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 9 & 8 & 10 & 4 & 9 & 10 & 10 & 3 & 3 & 10 & 0 & 9 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 10 & 3 & 3 & 6 \\
26 & 11 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 45 & 2663 & 10783 & 2658 & 47 & 10 & 2 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 5 & 2 & 5 & 10 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 6 & 9 & 8 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 5 & 0 \\
27 & 4 & 6 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 9 & 3 & 1 & 9 & 4 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 10 & 2 & 2 & 8 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 4 & 44 & 164 & 42 & 3 & 3 & 9 & 3 & 9 & 6 & 4 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 10 & 6 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 9 & 1 \\
28 & 1 & 9 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 7 & 6 & 10 & 9 & 9 & 3 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 6 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 10 & 2 & 6 & 9 & 1 & 5 & 8 & 5 & 9 & 5 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 10 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 0 & 2 \\
29 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 9 & 1 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 2 & 1 & 9 & 9 & 2 & 7 & 10 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 9 & 6 & 0 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 0 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 0 & 6 & 6 & 0 & 9 & 9 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 6 & 6 \\
30 & 2 & 1 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 9 & 2 & 0 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 10 & 5 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 10 & 2 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 5 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 4 & 6 & 1 & 3 & 8 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 8 & 5 \\
31 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 8 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 10 & 4 & 0 & 7 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 9 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 1 & 9 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 7 & 5 & 0 & 8 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 5 & 9 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 6 & 0 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
32 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 9 & 3 & 5 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 9 & 8 & 5 & 3 & 6 & 8 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 2 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 8 & 5 & 5 & 9 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 5 & 10 & 2 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 1 & 3 & 4 \\
33 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 9 & 9 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 9 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 10 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 9 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 3 \\
34 & 5 & 7 & 0 & 9 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 5 & 10 & 9 & 10 & 8 & 10 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 8 & 9 & 4 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 27 & 94 & 24 & 2 & 2 & 5 & 10 \\
35 & 7 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 9 & 7 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 3 & 9 & 6 & 9 & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 8 & 2 & 9 & 7 & 1 & 9 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 5 & 7 & 3 & 9 & 11 & 95 & 355 & 96 & 7 & 7 & 8 & 8 \\
36 & 1 & 10 & 2 & 8 & 8 & 3 & 0 & 7 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 0 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 8 & 6 & 5 & 5 & 0 & 2 & 8 & 10 & 10 & 23 & 94 & 25 & 8 & 7 & 0 & 8 \\
37 & 7 & 9 & 7 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 8 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 9 & 0 & 7 & 2 & 5 & 9 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 7 & 10 & 7 & 4 & 6 & 2 & 9 & 6 & 6 & 9 & 11 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 10 & 2 \\
38 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 5 & 7 & 6 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 8 & 7 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 9 & 1 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 6 & 4 & & 2 & 4 & 9 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 3  \\
39 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 8 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 10 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 9 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 0 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 6 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 6 & 2 \\
40 & 1 & 8 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 7 & 10 & 7 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 9 & 3 & 7 & 9 & 9 & 7 & 6 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 0 & 14 & 38 & 12 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 4 \\
41 & 6 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 4 & 8 & 10 & 7 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 9 & 2 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 7 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 7 & 9 & 6 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 15 & 505 & 2041 & 510 & 9 & 0 & 1 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 9 & 8 & 10 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
42 & 1 & 7 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 4 & 9 & 1 & 8 & 2 & 9 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 2 & 7 & 8 & 2 & 0 & 9 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 6 & 7 & 37 & 2040 & 8236 & 2031 & 35 & 7 & 7 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 7 & 2 & 5 & 2 & 0 & 8 \\
43 & 1 & 7 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 10 & 4 & 8 & 7 & 7 & 2 & 7 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 7 & 10 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 16 & 508 & 2040 & 504 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 9 & 2 & 7 & 7 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 7 \\
44 & 8 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 7 & 10 & 10 & 4 & 1 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 10 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 10 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 40 & 10 & 2 & 8 & 3 & 3 & 7 & 4 & 9 & 9 & 2 & 7 & 3 & 1 \\
45 & 5 & 10 & 8 & 8 & 4 & 10 & 8 & 5 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 8 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 9 & 2 & 9 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 6 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 4 & 10 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 3 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 8 & 1 & 1 \\
46 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 0 & 9 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 2 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 10 & 6 & 8 & 7 & 8 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 8 & 10 & 2 & 1 & 9 & 9 & 0 & 6 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 0 \\
47 & 7 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 8 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 0 & 10 & 1 & 6 & 8 & 6 & 8 & 0 & 6 & 2 & 10 & 2 & 10 & 8 & 5 & 8 & 6 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 9 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 9 & 8 & 10 & 3 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 5 \\
48 & 1 & 8 & 2 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 2 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 6 & 2 & 8 & 4 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 8 & 4 & 0 & 8 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 7 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 7 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 9 & 9 & 3 & 9 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 1 \\
49 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 1 & 1 & 5 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 8 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 8 & 10 & 8 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 6 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 9 & 3 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 0 & 9 & 8 \\
50 & 6 & 2 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 7 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 9 & 6 & 6 & 2 & 7 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 8 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 7 & 0 & 5 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 7 & 7 & 0 & 1 & 6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i have some problems with the rotating package

Comment: You should ask a new question focused on the `rotating` package demonstrating your problem.